# Javascripts interfering with each other on load

Tags: javascript, html, connection, dom-events

I am having an issue with my javascript files interfering with each other. I have tested them separately and they will load when the other script is not in the HTML. Below is my html documentation and attached js files I am loading in from another file. What am I doing wrong here?

HTML

```
<body>
    <div>
       <h1 id=sector1></h1>
        <script>
          document.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (document.readyState === 'complete')
            {
                sectorperformance();
            }
          };
        </script>
     </div>    
     <div class="row-news-article">
                  <h3 id=headline3></h3>
                  <p id=summary3></p>
                  <a id=link3 target="_blank">read more...</a>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <script>
               document.onreadystatechange = function() {
                  if (document.readyState === 'complete')
                  {
                     news();
                  }
                };
              </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/news.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/tickertape.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/sectorperformance.js' %}"></script>
</body>
```

news.js

```
function news() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var newsfeed = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("headline1").innerHTML = newsfeed[0]["headline"];
      document.getElementById("summary1").innerHTML = newsfeed[0]["summary"];
      document.getElementById("link1").href = newsfeed[0]["url"];
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/spy/news/last/1?token=pk_6925213461cb489b8c04a632e18c25dd", false);
  xhttp.send();
};
```

sectorperformance.js

```
  function sectorperformance() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var sectorperformance = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("sector1").innerHTML = sectorperformance[0]["name"];
      document.getElementById("performance1").innerHTML = sectorperformance[0]["performance"];
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/sector-performance?token=pk_6925213461cb489b8c04a632e18c25dd", false);
  xhttp.send();
};
```

Comment: have you tried prefacing them with `async` in the script declaration? `<script async type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/news.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: I just gave that a shot, however, it didn't seem to fix the error, unfortunately. Would it make sense if because both calls are labeled 'document.readyState === 'complete'' they're waiting for each other to load?